# Is "fr, en; q=0.3" a valid Accept-Language value?

Tags: html

According to the RFC, it's okay to have *LWS between words and separators. However, if you look at the specific ABNF for matching the Accept-Language field, it doesn't allow for whitespace around the `;` character.

Here is the exact [LWS specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html):

> **implied *LWS**: The grammar described by this specification is
>   word-based. Except where noted otherwise, linear white space (LWS) can
>   be included between any two adjacent words (token or quoted-string),
>   and between adjacent words and separators, without changing the
>   interpretation of a field. At least one delimiter (LWS and/or
>   separators) MUST exist between any two tokens (for the definition of
>   "token" below), since they would otherwise be interpreted as a single
>   token.

Here is the [ABNF grammar](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4):

```
   Accept-Language = "Accept-Language" ":"
                     1#( language-range [ ";" "q" "=" qvalue ] )
   language-range  = ( ( 1*8ALPHA *( "-" 1*8ALPHA ) ) | "*" )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is a more recent RFC which clarifies this.

```
weight = OWS ";" OWS "q=" qvalue
qvalue = ( "0" [ "." 0*3DIGIT ] )
      / ( "1" [ "." 0*3("0") ] )
```

https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#quality.values

Thus the answer is thus YES, it is valid.